# Why did "Star Trek: The Next Generation" become more militaristic in later seasons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

I always wondered why *Star Trek: The Next Generation* took a formula of being militaristic (and the scores got more militaristic too) in later seasons?

I'm thinking "Best of Both Worlds" and "The Wounded" might have something to do with this, as the latter is what introduced us to what would become a recurring enemy in *Star Trek* franchise in the years to come, the Cardassians. Is that why?

Comment: The in-universe answer seems obvious; they responded to a change in the political climate. Are you specifically asking for an out-of-universe answer like why did the production execs push the overall storyline into more inter-species conflict? Can you [edit] your question to specify what you expect as a response?

Comment: Is it possible once Roddenberry died and his influence began to wane they went to more violent storylines?

Comment: @kingofpanes - From what I understand the Original Number 1/Nurse Chapel/Computer voice/Lwaxana Troi was a woman not to be trifled with and she shared Roddenberry's vision of the future.

Comment: I am not sure that the premise of this question is correct.  Seasons 4+ still contain lots of examples of episodes where a non-aggressive solution is chosen (such as *I, Borg*) and episodes where communication and diplomacy is more important than war (such as *Darmok*).

Comment: And even when militaristic elements were present, they certainly weren't glorified.  For example, in *The Pegasus*, the hawkish wing of Starfleet (represented by Admiral Pressman) is pretty much the villain.

Comment: Like there was more war as theme in later episodes. In part "Best of Both Worlds" started this, but it was really with "Ensign Ro" that we see large scale conflicts regularly - in that episode the Cardassians oppress the Bajorans. Then we have "Chain of Command." Then the battles with the renegade Borg.